# How to create xls file after success to generate to excel file

Tags: php, sql-server, excel

I have the code like this :

```
<?php
include "ExcelUtil.php";
include "admin/doconnect.php";

class ExcelGenerator {
    var $xls;

    function ExcelGenerator() 
    {
        $this->xls = new ExcelUtil();
    }
function saveToExcel($pageFunction, $searchdate1, $searchdate2, $person, $type, $ewonumber, $device1, $device2, $subjectx) 

    {        
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
        header ("Content-Description: PHP/INTERBASE Generated Data");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Reportxls");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

$query = "select * from activity WHERE actiondate BETWEEN '$tanggal' AND '$now' order by actiondate DESC";
    $hasil = mssql_query($query);

    echo "<table width=\"97%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Action Date</th>";
    echo "<th>Person</th>";
    echo "<th>Subject</th>";
    echo "<th>EWO Number / TR Number</th>";
    echo "<th>Category</th>";
    echo "<th>Device</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($data = mssql_fetch_array($hasil))
    {
        echo "<tr valign='top'>";
        echo "<td class=\"isitabel\" align='center'>$data[actiondate]</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"isitabel\" align='left'>$data[person]</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"isitabel\" align='left'>$data[subject]</td>";
            if ($data[tr_number]=="" || $data[tr_number]=="-") {
            $data[tr_number] = "";
            }else if ($data[ewo_number]=="" || $data[ewo_number]=="-") {
                $data[ewo_number] = "";
                    }
        echo "<td class=\"isitabel\"align='center'>$data[ewo_number]$data[tr_number]</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"isitabel\" align='center'>$data[category]</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"isitabel\" align='center'>$data[device]</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"isitabel\" align='center'>$data[status]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
    }
}

$generator = new ExcelGenerator();
$generator->saveToExcel();
?>
```

From that code, I have successfully convert to xls file with the name = Report.xls when download prompt appear.

In my case, I want to give some code to write its xls file to my directory (C:/) automatically without user must click "Save" on download prompt.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: I had to spend all my energy formatting your code and removing your begging, and now I have none left to answer your "urgent" question!

Comment: i'm so sorry, it's my 1st post..

Comment: The FAQ is visible from before you even register.

Comment: **What about us poor Ubuntu users who don't have C:/ drives?** Do any modern versions of Windows even let the user write to C:/ anymore without admin privileges?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do this of course.

Can you **imagine** the security flaw in that idea?

Comment: @Ryanta: As a user, do you want websites downloading files onto your PC wherever they please, without asking or even telling you? No, of course you don't.

Comment: this is in server side, not in user.
i have computer server that can automatically start the php file.
So that the code above is automatically proceed each day.
i just want to add simple code at the end to save that xls file automatically to C:// directory.
but, thanks for ur answer..

Comment: @Ryanta: What's the HTTP and HTML for, then?

Comment: Yeaah,,,..
finally i can build it with myself.
U say that it's impossible..but actually it's possible.

Comment: @Ryanta: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that. The user must confirm the file download.

Comment: but when i want to copy that file on t C:/ directory, it must be possible. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Ryanta: Didn't two people just tell you that it is not possible?